# Write the first set of rows

Tags: python, csv

I am parsing through a csv file and deleting the first column, this has been accomplished. I request your assistance in how to tell Python to skip rows and only write rows that have meaningful data in it.

```
Result CSV:

Presented_By       Sources        Salesman
 John               Radio          Mary   
 Edwin              Newspaper      Bexie
 Ben                Radio          Jon




                   Radio               2
                   Newspaper           1
```

I want to exclude the part at the bottom where the sources are being counted. What can I add to my snippet that will tell Python to ignore the second part.

```
import csv
with open("InfoCenterTracker.csv","rb") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )
    with open("result.csv","wb") as result:
        wtr= csv.writer( result )
        for r in rdr:
            wtr.writerow( (r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6], r[7], r[8], r[9], r[10], r[11], r[12], r[13], r[14], r[15], r[16], r[17], r[18]) )

        print "Column deleted"
```

Comment: check what you have in row before you write it and write or not write in file. You can use `if`, `for` and maybe `all()` or `any()`.

Comment: Yes Furas, I can tell Python to only write rows that have values in the first column.

Comment: `if r[1]: wtr.writerow(...)`? Only you know the structure of *csv* file, so you need to implement filtering by your own.

Comment: BTW instead of `(r[1], ..., r[18])` you can use `r[1:19]`

Comment: Rookie mistake Furas lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be correct to assume any row with an empty first column is to be skipped? Are there any rows of actual data with an empty first row?

if that is safe to do, you can add:

```
if r[1] == "": 
  pass
else:
   wtr.writerow(<Row contents>)
```

I'm wondering if your double parentheses are intentional? maybe it can be shortened to

```
wtr.writerow(r)
```

Comment: you could write it without `pass` - see @AndrejsCainikovs comment above.

Comment: Yes Owen that is correct.If the first column has NO value skip it. Yes the double parenthesis is a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement to check the contents of `r[0]` if it's empty and `r[1]` is not empty `continue` the loop.

Also you don't need to write every item of the list for arguments..

You can use `*r[starting:end index]` to expand the list into arguments in function call. If it needs **tuple** use `tuple(r[start:end])` as the argument